# Issue with COPY command during building Docker Image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, .net-framework, docker-for-windows

I have the following Docker file to build a .NET Core web application to be hosted on a Linux container -

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ARP.API.Policies/ARP.API.Policies.csproj", "ARP.API.Policies/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ARP.API.Policies/ARP.API.Policies.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ARP.API.Policies"
RUN dotnet build "ARP.API.Policies.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ARP.API.Policies.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ARP.API.Policies.dll"]
```

My local dev machine is running Docker Desktop for Windows in Linux containers mode. Everything works fine here.
When I try to run the same Docker build on an actual Linux system(in this case, it's a build server running ubuntu 1604, it fails with the error :

COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder791807544/ARP.API.Policies/ARP.API.Policies.csproj: no such file or directory
/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1

Any ideas are most appreciated. Please note that my project structure has both the file to be copied 'ARP.API.Policies.csproj' and the Dockerfile at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that the .csproj is in the same directory as the Dockerfile, but the Dockerfile you list refers to it in a subdirectory ARP.API.Policies.

Is it possible that you rearranged things a little bit when you copied it to the Ubuntu box, perhaps only copied the ARP.API.Policies directory and put the Dockerfile in there?

If that's the case you could simply use

```
COPY ARP.API.Policies.csproj ./
WORKDIR /src
```

Also, it's very useful to build in WSL on your local machine. Windows VS Code works really nicely with WSL: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the Build context property in the Docker build task in Azure Devops build pipeline had to be set to $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory). By default it is set to ** -
[Build context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzCF9.png)